# Pytorch: Accessing batches of images from different classes from the generic dataloader

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to train a GAN using tensorflow and pytorch. I'm using the torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root, transform=None, target_transform=None, loader=) class to load the images. I have two classes: Negatives and Positives. How can I access a batch of negative and positive images from the dataloader when I'm iterating through it. Look at the dataloader iteration in the training loop. Here is the code:

```
DATA_FOLDER = './tf_data/plasmodium_photos/'
IMAGE_PIXELS = 28*28*3
NOISE_SIZE = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 10


def noise(n_rows, n_cols):
    return np.random.normal(size=(n_rows, n_cols))

def xavier_init(size):
    in_dim = size[0] if len(size) == 1 else size[1]
    stddev = 1. / np.sqrt(float(in_dim))
    return tf.random_uniform(shape=size, minval=-stddev, maxval=stddev)

def images_to_vectors(images):
    return images.reshape(images.shape[0], 2352)


def vectors_to_images(vectors):
    return vectors.reshape(vectors.shape[0], 28, 28, 3)


def plasmodium_data():
    compose = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(),
         transforms.Normalize((.5, .5, .5), (.5, .5, .5))
        ])
    return datasets.ImageFolder(DATA_FOLDER, transform=compose)



# Load data
data = plasmodium_data()

# Create loader with data, so that we can iterate over it
data_loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)


# Num batches
num_batches = len(data_loader)


## Discriminator

# Input
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, IMAGE_PIXELS))

# Layer 1 Variables
D_W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([2352, 1024]))
D_B1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([1024]))

# Layer 2 Variables
D_W2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([1024, 512]))
D_B2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([512]))

# Layer 3 Variables
D_W3 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([512, 256]))
D_B3 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([256]))

# Out Layer Variables
D_W4 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([256, 1]))
D_B4 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([1]))

# Store Variables in list
D_var_list = [D_W1, D_B1, D_W2, D_B2, D_W3, D_B3, D_W4, D_B4]


## setting up a Generator network

# Input
Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, NOISE_SIZE))

# Layer 1 Variables
G_W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([10, 256]))
G_B1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([256]))

# Layer 2 Variables
G_W2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([256, 512]))
G_B2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([512]))

# Layer 3 Variables
G_W3 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([512, 1024]))
G_B3 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([1024]))

# Out Layer Variables
G_W4 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([1024, 2352]))
G_B4 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([2352]))

# Store Variables in list
G_var_list = [G_W1, G_B1, G_W2, G_B2, G_W3, G_B3, G_W4, G_B4]

def discriminator(x):
    l1 = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(x,   D_W1) + D_B1, .2), .3)
    l2 = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l1,  D_W2) + D_B2, .2), .3)
    l3 = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l2,  D_W3) + D_B3, .2), .3)
    out = tf.matmul(l3, D_W4) + D_B4
    return out

def generator(z):
    l1 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(z,  G_W1) + G_B1, .2)
    l2 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l1, G_W2) + G_B2, .2)
    l3 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(l2, G_W3) + G_B3, .2)
    out = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(l3, G_W4) + G_B4)
    return out

G_sample = generator(Z)
D_real = discriminator(X)
D_fake = discriminator(G_sample)

# Losses
D_loss_real = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_real, labels=tf.ones_like(D_real)))
D_loss_fake = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_fake, labels=tf.zeros_like(D_fake)))
D_loss = D_loss_real + D_loss_fake
G_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_fake, labels=tf.ones_like(D_fake)))

# Optimizers
D_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(2e-4).minimize(D_loss, var_list=D_var_list)
G_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(2e-4).minimize(G_loss, var_list=G_var_list)

# Testing configuration
num_test_samples = 100
test_noise = noise(num_test_samples, NOISE_SIZE)

# Variable initialization
num_epochs = 200

# Start interactive session
session = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Init Variables
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

# Init Logger
# Needed to make sure the logging output is visible.
  # See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3047
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

X_batch = None
Z_batch = None
#Training
# Iterate through epochs
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for n_batch, (batch, label) in enumerate(data_loader):

        #print(epoch)
        # 1. Train Discriminator
        print(label)
        #print(type(batch))
        #print(batch.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).shape)
        X_batch = images_to_vectors(batch.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).numpy())
        feed_dict = {X: X_batch, Z: noise(BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_SIZE)}
        _, d_error, d_pred_real, d_pred_fake = session.run(
            [D_opt, D_loss, D_real, D_fake], feed_dict=feed_dict
        )

        # 2. Train Generator
        feed_dict = {Z: noise(BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_SIZE)}
        _, g_error = session.run(
            [G_opt, G_loss], feed_dict=feed_dict
        )

        if n_batch % 5 == 0:
            display.clear_output(True)
            # Generate images from test noise
            test_images = session.run(
                G_sample, feed_dict={Z: test_noise}
            )
            test_images = vectors_to_images(test_images)
            # Log Images
            for i in range(len(test_images)):
                imgplot = plt.imshow(test_images[i])


            # Log Status
            #tf.logging.info(
            #    epoch, num_epochs, n_batch, num_batches,
            #    d_error, g_error, d_pred_real, d_pred_fake
            #)
```

Comment: As far as I understand your code is doing this (I did not run the code): getting the batch of positive and negative samples from the data. Did you mean that you want the batch to be filled ONLY with positive or ONLY with negative samples?

Comment: @ManuelLagunas That is exactly what I meant. Apology if the message did not pass across.

Comment: I suggest you design your own DataSet to add this functionality. Just copy the source code for the ImageFolder Pytorch DataSet and specify in the init a list of indices that either refer only to positive or negative examples depending on an argument you pass.